# Is Stockholm's amusement park "Gröna Lund" open during the Christmas season?

Tags: public-holidays, seasonal, stockholm, amusement-parks

I've read some quotes about the Gröna Lund being open in December (at least there is supposed to be a Christmas market there) but the official website is strangely silent.

Does anyone know if the Gröna Lund amusement park is open in December?

Comment: I still don't get why we don't have a "Christmas" tag. I know it's been debated and decided against in the past but jeez.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6na_Lund), the park is closed from mid-September to April and the Christmas market was discontinued in 2009. The [calendar on the park's website](http://www.gronalund.com/en/Plan-Your-Visit/Calendar/) supports this - it shows the park as open every day in August, only Thrusday to Sunday in September, and only concert events (which are held on the premises while the rest of the park is closed) afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Gröna Lund is closed during Christmas. As far as I know they have never been opened during this time of year. I think your Christmas market reference may refer to one of:

- Skansen - the zoo and outdoors museum close to Gröna Lund has a Christmas market on weekends in December. It is at Bollnästorget from 10 to 16. [More info in swedish](http://www.skansen.se/sv/aktivitet/julmarknad-2013).
- Liseberg - the amusement park of Gothenburg (the large city on the west coast) is [opened for christmas](http://liseberg.com/en/home/Christmas-at-Liseberg/) from mid-November to the end of December. Not sure about the market though.
- The [Christmas market at Stortorget](http://stortorgetsjulmarknad.com/en/index.php) in the old town. It is open daily between 11 and 16 from 23/11 to 23/12.

Both Skansen and Stortorget are nice but if you want to combine with amusement park activities you'll have to go to Gothenburg.